# How to build Side Bar Menu which shows on mouse hover on pyqt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I have been trying to build an app which has a dynamic side bar. I am using qtdesigner and pyqt5. I tryed in two ways:

1) Using stylesheet whith hover. But the sidebar (frame) has buttons on it. It happens that when I see the bar I just can see the button which has the mouse on.

stylesheetcode:

```
QFrame {
                  background-color: rgba(255, 151, 231, 0); 
             }

QFrame:hover {
               background-color:rgba(255, 151, 231, 0.45)
            }

QPushButton {
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                background-color: rgba(255, 151, 231, 0);  
             }

QPushButton:hover {
               background-color:rgba(255, 151, 231, 0.45);
            }
```

output: (the mouse is over the button)

[image]

I know why it happens but I dont know how to solve it.

2) Using Events

Using events I can reach what I want, but I am not sure if I am doing the right thig.

```
  class TelaPrincipal(QDialog, QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TelaPrincipal, self).__init__(parent)
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        Ui_Form.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # -- Barra lateral esconde esconde --
        # instala esse EventFilter
        qApp.installEventFilter(self)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.frame.hide)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
         # do not hide frame when frame shown
        if qApp.activePopupWidget() is None:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
                if self.frame.isHidden():
                    self.frame.show()
                    rect = self.geometry()
                    # set mouse-sensitive zone
                    rect.setHeight(25)
                    if rect.contains(event.globalPos()):
                        self.frame.show()
                else:
                    rect = QtCore.QRect(
                        self.frame.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)),
                        self.frame.size())
                    if not rect.contains(event.globalPos()):
                        self.frame.hide()
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave and source is self:
                self.frame.hide()
        return QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = TelaPrincipal()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

What do you suggest me ??

Comment: So have you solved this using events?

Comment: @xyres. It works fairly well. But I still wondering if I could solve it just with css. About this code, instead of setting the rect high I am going to use the frame high. I also read about using QPropertyAnimation, but I did not go in deep ..

Comment: Well, you can change stylesheet of all buttons when mouse is hovered over the frame. But you'd still need to use events for mouse hover (`enterEvent`).

Comment: @xyres, I tried to use enterEvent, but it just worked when the mouse cursor was coming from outside the window (the main frame), but when it left the frame then entered again it did not work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent a little time reading the docs. The simplest way I found was this:

in the class init I installed a filter, then I overide the eventFilter method.

```
class MainScreen(QMainWindow, QDialog,  Ui_TelaPrincipal):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(parent)
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        Ui_MainScreen.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # ---- side bar ---- #
        # installs a filter event
        qApp.installEventFilter(self)
        # hide the bar 
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.plano_barra.hide)

        self.plano_central.setMouseTracking(1)
        self.plano_botao_barra.setMouseTracking(1)
        self.setMouseTracking(1)
        self.plano_principal.setMouseTracking(1)


    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            if source == self.plano_botao_barra:
                print("i am over the button")
                self.plano_barra.show()

            if source == self.plano_central:
                print("i am at the main plan")
                self.plano_barra.hide()

        return QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

Comment: If you use `super`, you don't need to call the `__init__` of all the base-classes as well (and you should also use `super` in the event-filter). It is also wrong to inherit from both `QMainWindow` and `QDialog`, so get rid of the latter.